# How to detect keyboard shortcuts / bindings destinations and render them to the screen?

Tags: keyboard

I have some key bindings / chords that seem to do things that are unexpected sometimes and they're not being mapped within the System Preferences nor in other apps that I would normally use to control such things. Is there a way to have an application that monitors keyboard input in relation to applications or various services and tells what each keypress / key combo / key chord is actually trying to do?

A small, but perhaps crude, example might be the use of `which -a` in the shell where it lists all commands that would match a command in order of priority.

Comment: Would https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/ help?

Comment: Hey this is excellent - I think. Will this give systemwide shortcuts as well that are even pertinent outside of the current app in focus if they're globals?